# How to view electric charges creating electric fields

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

What is the best way mentally think of how a particle with electric charge creates an electric field? Is it to think that field lines propagate, extend, radiate (whatever verb you want to use) etc., from within the source charge? or that "charge" is some type of aura, aether around a particle and it expands outward from the the particle creating what we refer to as 'electric field'. I understand these scenarios can be considered a bit naïve and foolish, but im trying to get a better VISUAL understanding of what's going on when a charge particle creates an electric field around it.

Answer (score 1):

We model the charge as being contained within the particle or charged body, not extending beyond its boundaries.

This model helps to visualize how, when the particle moves, it takes some time (due to light speed delay) for the field around it to respond. If we considered the charge as extending beyond the particle, then we'd have to explain how does the fact of the particle's motion get communicated to the charge far away from the particle.

This model is also necessary to use Gauss's law for electrostatic fields in its usual formulations (integral and differential forms).

Comment: Thats a very fair point about why the "charge" is confined to the particle. What does that say then about how to visualize the electric field forming?

Comment: @Jake, lots of people visualize it using the field lines concept. Then Gauss's law tells you the field lines must terminate on charge elements. If you're trying to visualize a dynamic situation (i.e. where field retardation is significant) then it's a bit trickier and I don't know a better way than to actually solve the equations (or do a numerical simulation) and let your software plot the E and H fields.

Comment: @ The Photon so for a thought experiment, lets say a charged particle comes into existence...would field lines just start to radiate or 'grow'  from the charged particle?

Comment: @Jake, conceivably, yes. But because charge is a conserved quantity, this can't happen. The closest thing that really happens is a neutral particle gets split into a positive and negative part, and those parts separate from each other. In that case you can visualize the field pattern around a dipole adjusting itself to become the field pattern of two separated charges.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but if you want to gain some intuition for why electric fields and field lines are the way they are at steady state, the flow of an incompressible fluid might be a useful analogy. The equations describing electrostatics in vacuum are exactly the same as those describing incompressible flow. In this analogy, imagine the entire space is filled with this fluid (no gravity). Charge ($\text C$) becomes source of fluid volume per unit time ($\text m^3 \text{/s}$), and electric field ($\vec D = \epsilon_0\vec E$, $\text{C/m}^2$) becomes fluid velocity ($\text{m/s}$). A positive point charge can be thought of as a tiny volume injecting fluid into space at a constant rate, and a negative charge sinks fluid. At any point, the electric field vector gives you the velocity at which a fluid particle is moving.

Electric field lines are the trajectories you trace if you follow any fluid particle over the course of its motion. Particles begin their journey at a fluid source (a positive charge), and follow trajectories that terminate either at a fluid sink (a negative charge), or at infinity, if there are more sources than sinks. If there are more sinks than sources, a particle may also begin its trajectory at infinity and terminate at a sink.

Transient changes to the electric field due to changes in charge configuration can be thought of as radiating outward from the point of "disturbance" at the speed of light, as The Photon explains. This is described precisely by [Jefimenko's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jefimenko%27s_equations), where the role of the speed of light is explicit in the retarded time that appears in the equations. Note however that charges can't pop into existence out of nowhere, this is not consistent with Maxwell's equations (specifically, conservation of charge).